# What is the difference of xgboost and sagemaker.xgboost

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

Question is really clear. Nowadays im learning AWS world, and this question is eating my head up. What is the difference of `import xgboost` and `import sagemaker.xgboost`.

On SageMaker i can work with normal XGBoost library, and i know i can select different EC2 types with `sagemaker.xgboost`. But except this, what is the difference?
Are there any big difference?

Answer (score 1):

Using model training as an example task: `sagemaker.xgboost` provides the ability to create Amazon SageMaker training jobs (and related AWS resources) in an environment that has the XGBoost library installed. So `import xgboost` gives you the modules for writing a training script that actually trains a model whereas `import sagemaker.xgboost` gives you modules for performing the training task on SageMaker.

The same applies for other tasks (e.g. predictions).

SageMaker XGBoost documentation: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/xgboost/using_xgboost.html#use-the-open-source-xgboost-algorithm